# NoClassDefFoundError when run Java ME project which, use Bouncy Castle Library

Tags: jar, java-me, base64, midlet

I wanna use decode Base64 function in Java ME project so, I add **bcprov-jdk15on-149.jar** to my project.([Bouncy Castle Library](http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html))

By [Adding Hardware JAR Files](http://eclipseme.org/docs/advJarFiles.html#hardware), I got this error:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/util/encoders/Base64

Then, I try [Adding Application JAR Files](http://eclipseme.org/docs/advJarFiles.html#application), I got another error; The project package got red cross and I cannot run the project.

I'm not sure what did I do wrong, you guy have any suggestion?

(I use Eclipse Java ME Nokia sdk 2.0,  JRE1.7U17  , JDK1.7u17)